# WordPress-like Sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code for a sidebar (similar to WordPress).

I have multiple Parent classes `<li class="panel parent">`. One of the parent has a child container with Notes Received, and Notes Sent. Currently when I click the parent the child is working, and if I select other parents the child is closing as well.

I have used the `addClass` in jQuery to select both parent and child.

**The Issue is**
When I reload the page, `addClass` disappeared from the parent. I believe you can make it work with `localStorage` but i don't know how to use it.

Can you help me out. 
Sorry for my English.

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <ul id="accordion" class="sidebar-menu grandparent">
            <li class="panel parent">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#notes" href="#"> Vegetables </a>
                 <div id="notes" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <!-- children -->
                    <ul class="children">
                        <li><a href="#"> Potato </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"> Tomato </a></li>
                        ...
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="panel parent">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#dummychild" href="#">Fruits</a>
                <div id="dummychild" class="panel-collapse collapse"></div> <!-- dummy child -->
            </li>
            <li class="panel parent">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#dummychild" href="#">Spices</a>
                <div id="dummychild" class="panel-collapse collapse"></div> <!-- dummy child -->
            </li>
            ...
        </ul>   
    </div
</div>
```

**Here's my jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.grandparent').find('li a').click(function () {
        $('.grandparent').find('li a').removeClass('sidebar-hght');
        $(this).addClass('sidebar-hght');
        $($(this).closest('li.parent').children()[0]).addClass('sidebar-hght');
    });
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: so you would like that after the refresh the menu stays open, did I understand well?

Comment: thats right. I want the highlight to stay even after you refresh the page.

Comment: In what way is this _similar to wordpress_ ? You mean that Wordpress themes sometimes have a sidebar? This has no relation to Wordpress

Comment: @Lee, sorry man, i'll take a note and check the tags next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OLD ANSWER**

you should exec this

```
window.localStorage.setItem('OPEN', 'YES');
```

or this

```
window.localStorage.setItem('OPEN', 'YES');
```

depending if you are going to show or close the side menu.
Then your jQuery should become like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.grandparent').find('li a').click(function () {
        $('.grandparent').find('li a').removeClass('sidebar-hght');
        $(this).addClass('sidebar-hght');
        $($(this).closest('li.parent').children()[0]).addClass('sidebar-hght');
    });
    if( window.localStorage.getItem('OPEN') ==='YES' ) {
        /* put here your code to add the class "addClass" to the parents you want */
    }
});
```

**EDIT: NEW ANSWER BASED ON JSFIDDLE**

this javascript code will do the magic

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.grandparent').find('li a').click(function () {
        $('.grandparent').find('li a').removeClass('sidebar-hght');
        $(this).addClass('sidebar-hght');
        window.localStorage.setItem('OPEN', $(this).html());
        alert("set OPEN to "+$(this).html());
        $($(this).closest('li.parent').children()[0]).addClass('sidebar-hght');
    });
    if( window.localStorage.getItem('OPEN') ) {
       $('.grandparent').find('li a').each(function( index ) {
          if($(this).html() === window.localStorage.getItem('OPEN'))
              $(this).click();
       });
    }
});
```

Comment: thank man. There is no open and close in the sidebar, it is just a highlight on the menu. - i have created the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Hive/c0v2rmr0/

Comment: @Hive, I answered again with a new solution based on your jsFiddle, please try it

Comment: this is great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Hive, Vote up and accept my answer if it solved your issue